# Resident function isn't correctly carried out

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

Again i come face to face with a problem display of a name of the file. Why again?

Resident function changes the catalog and displays line, but doesn't display a file name.  I cause function from other program.

```
.model  tiny
.code
.186
org 100h
main:  mov  ah, 33h
       int  60h
       ret
       end  main
```

If number of function is not correct that the mistake will be displayed:
"Function %somefunction% is not realised".

My number of function 33h, i have to receive the message  "The file with the oldest date of creation: %myoldfile%" , but
i receive only line without name of file.

```
.MODEL tiny
.code
.386

org     100h

main:


jmp init

Int_60h:
xor     cx, cx
mov     cl, ah
push    ds
pusha
mov     bl, ah
sal     bx, 1
mov     ax, cs
mov     ds, ax
call    TAB[bx]
popa
mov     bl, count
pop     ds
iret






OldFile PROC 

mov ah,3bh
mov dx,offset root ; Change directory to the root
int 21h

lea dx, dta ; dta: disk transfer area
mov ah, 1AH ; SET DISK TRANSFER AREA ADDRESS
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT

mov ah, 4EH ; FIND FIRST MATCHING FILE
lea dx, path ; DS:DX -> ASCIZ file specification (may include path and wildcards)
mov cx, 0 ; file attribute mask
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT

call store_dta


FindNext:

mov ah, 4FH ; FIND NEXT MATCHING FILE
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT
jc Finish

; compare filedates & filetimes
lea si, dta_hold ; DTA of the oldest file
lea di, dta ; DTA of the just found file
mov ax, [si+18h] ; filedate
mov bx, [di+18h] ; filedate
cmp ax, bx
jc FindNext ; just found file is newer
jne Older
; filedates are identical
mov ax, [si+16h] ; filetime
mov bx, [di+16h] ; filetime
cmp ax, bx
jc FindNext

Older: ; just found file is older
call store_dta ; copy dta to dta_hold
jmp FindNext

Finish:
call print_filename ; print the last filename




store_dta PROC
mov cx, (128/2) ; size of DTA in WORDs (half of BYTEs)
lea si, dta
lea di, dta_hold
rep movsw ; copy CX times DS:SI => ES:DI
ret
store_dta ENDP

print_filename PROC

lea dx, line ; new line
mov ah, 09h ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT

lea di, dta_hold + 1Eh
mov dx, di ; start of filename
_B: ; look for NULL (ASCIZ-termination)
cmp BYTE PTR [di], 0
je _F
inc di
jmp _B
_F: ; replace NULL by '$'
mov [di], BYTE PTR '$' ; end-of-string delimiter for INT 21h/09h
mov ah, 09h ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT

lea dx, LF ; new line
mov ah, 09h ; WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT
int 21h ; DOS INTERRUPT
ret

dta db 128 DUP(?)
dta_hold db 128 DUP(?)
path db "*.*",0
LF db 13,10,'$'
root db "/",0
line db "The file with the oldest date of creation: ",'$'

print_filename ENDP

    OldFile ENDP

    Zproc   proc    near 
xor     ax, ax
mov al, cl
mov cx, 5           
    L1:                 
xor dx, dx          
mov di, cx          
div hexdel
mov bx, dx          
mov dl, chararray[bx]   
mov Znum[di-1], dl  
dec cx
cmp ax, 0   
jne L1          
mov si, offset Zmessage1
 l4:    mov al, [si]
mov ah, 0Eh
inc si
int 10h
cmp byte ptr [si], '$'
jne l4
    ret
Zproc   endp




TAB dw  51 DUP (Zproc), (OldFile), 204 DUP (Zproc)
hexdel          dw  16
Zmessage1 db "Function "
Znum    db  3 dup (?)
Zmessage2 db "h is not realized.", 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
count   db      (?)
chararray   db '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C',      'D', 'E', 'F' 

init:
mov ax,2560h
mov dx,offset Int_60h
int 21h
mov dx, (init-main+10Fh)/16
mov ah, 31h
int 21h
end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you call your function with `call TAB[bx]` but don't fill `BX` correctly. `mov bl, ah` is not enough, because the value of `BH` has also an affect to `BX`. Write `XOR BX, BX` just before you fill `BL`:

```
xor     bx,bx
mov     bl, ah
```

The second is that the procedure `OldFile` doesn't return correctly. Insert a `ret` at the right place:

```
Finish:
call print_filename ; print the last filename
ret
```

Third: The procedure `store_dta` needs `ES` to be initialised:

```
mov     ds, ax
mov     es, ax
call    TAB[bx]
```

Comment: I added, but it didn't give effect.

Comment: @lifetowin, I forgot: The procedure `OldFile` doesn't return correctly. There is another ugly stuff in your code which could cause problems. It works in DOSBox, but there is a problem in WinXP which I couldn't figure out. Why the heck do you play with TSR?

Comment: @lifetowin: Ouch. Then you must clean up the procedures. Either 'PROC...ret,ENDP' or 'Label:...ret'. Furthermore, you must be prepared that the teacher will ask you at every line "why did you do that?".

Comment: Actually I won't show anything. I do it not for myself.
I simply wanted to try the assembler.

Comment: @lifetowin: Take a look at my upgraded post. That is how I get it working here. I suggest to try a newer assembler on a newer operating system ;-)

Comment: Strange I added, but all as before. Can because I use dosbox?

Comment: @lifetowin: Bewitched! A debugging procedure of mine was hiding a third error.

Comment: Many thanks. Everything works. Your help is  invaluable.